# ctags vim - go to method definition in same python class

Tags: python, vim, ctags

I have two classes in a python source file.

```
class A:
   def func(self):
       pass

class B:
   def func(self):
       pass

   def run(self):
       self.func()
```

When my cursor is in class B's `'self.func()'` line, if press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>, it goes to class A's func method. But instead I would like it to go B's func method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `<C-]>` command jumps to the *first* tag match, but it also takes a `[count]` to jump to another one.

Alternatively, you can use the `g<C-]>` command, which (like the `:tjump` Ex command) will list all matches and query you for where you want to jump to (when there are multiple matches).

Comment: And how can I grep these :tselect list? I'm in a huge project with more than 100 functions definitions, I can't look for every one of them in a limite list like the :tselect one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Jedi-Vim](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim). It defines a new “go to definition” command, that will properly handle those situations.